# Summarize with rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Suppose, I've a `data.frame` as follows:

```
set.seed(45)
DF <- data.frame(x=1:10, strata2013=sample(letters[1:3], 10, TRUE))

    x strata2013
1   1          b
2   2          a
3   3          a
4   4          b
5   5          b
6   6          a
7   7          a
8   8          b
9   9          a
10 10          a
```

And I'd like to get the *counts* for *each unique value* in the column `strata2013`, then, using `data.table` (for speed), one could do it in this manner:

```
DT <- as.data.table(DF)
DT[, .N, by=strata2013]
   strata2013 N
1:          b 4
2:          a 6
```

---

Now, I'd like to try and accomplish this in `Rcpp`, as a learning exercise. I've written and tried out the code shown below which is supposed to provide the same output, but instead it gives me an error. Here's the code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;  

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector LengthStrata (CharacterVector uniqueStrata, DataFrame dataset ) {
  int n = uniqueStrata.size();
  NumericVector Nh(n);
  Rcpp::CharacterVector strata=dataset["strate2013"];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    Nh[i]=strata(uniqueStrata(i)).size();
  }
  return Nh;
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
conversion from 'Rcpp::Vector<16>::Proxy {aka Rcpp::internal::string_proxy<16>}' 
to 'const size_t { aka const long long unsigned int}' is ambiguous
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Is this a simplified example? Because from your description ist sounds like something that could be done very efficiently with R.

Comment: I know that aggregate function can do it easily, but I just want to compare...

Comment: I wasn't talking about `aggregate`. There are much more efficient alternatives. However, your description doesn't sound like it needs `aggregate`. But you are not explaining very clearly in your question.

Comment: `dataset[,.N,by=strate2013]` is very fast. Read the data.table vignettes.

Comment: dataset[,.N,by=strate2013] works fine, I've just tried... but my goal is to have an rcpp implementation of this

Comment: I've tried to salvage the post. Probably you should include the error you obtain instead of saying "I get an error". Error messages are informative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're hoping that `strata( uniqueStrata(i) )` will subset the vector, similar to how R's subsetting operates. This is unfortunately not the case; you would have to perform the subsetting 'by hand'. `Rcpp` doesn't have 'generic' subsetting operates available yet.

When it comes to using `Rcpp`, you really want to leverage the C++ standard library where possible. The de-facto C++ way of generating these counts would be to use a `std::map` (or `std::unordered_map`, if you can assume C++11), with something like the following. I include a benchmark for interest.

*Note from Dirk: `unordered_map` is actually available from `tr1` for pre-C++11, so one can include it using e.g. `#include <tr1/unordered_map>`*

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector LengthStrata( DataFrame dataset ) {
  Rcpp::CharacterVector strata = dataset["strata2013"];
  int n = strata.size();
  std::map<SEXP, int> counts;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    ++counts[ strata[i] ];
  }
  return wrap(counts);
}

/*** R
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(45)
DF <- data.frame(strata2013=sample(letters, 1E5, TRUE))
DT <- data.table(DF)
LengthStrata(DF)
DT[, .N, by=strata2013]
microbenchmark(
  LengthStrata(DF),
  DT[, .N, by=strata2013]
)
*/
```

gives me

```
Unit: milliseconds
                      expr      min       lq   median       uq       max neval
          LengthStrata(DF) 3.267131 3.831563 3.934992 4.101050 11.491939   100
 DT[, .N, by = strata2013] 1.980896 2.360590 2.480884 2.687771  3.052583   100
```

The `Rcpp` solution is slower in this case likely due to the time it takes to move R objects to and from the C++ containers, but hopefully this is instructive.

Aside: This is, in fact, already included in `Rcpp` as the sugar `table` function, so if you want to skip the learning experience, you can use a pre-baked solution as

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;  

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector LengthStrata( DataFrame dataset ) {
  Rcpp::CharacterVector strata = dataset["strata2013"];
  return table(strata);
}
```

Sugar improves the speed of the Rcpp function:

```
 Unit: milliseconds
                      expr      min       lq   median       uq       max neval
          LengthStrata(DF) 5.548094 5.870184 6.014002 6.448235  6.922062   100
 DT[, .N, by = strate2013] 6.526993 7.136290 7.462661 7.949543 81.233216   100
```

Comment: How can I know that a given function in R like table() is available in 'sugar'?

Comment: Two main ways: the [sugar vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-sugar.pdf), and browsing the [online doxygen documentation](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/html/dir_edae2c70406e9616e8689419d3d5106b.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do.  And when `strata` is a vector

```
     Rcpp::CharacterVector strata=df["strate2013"];
```

then I am not sure what

```
     strata(uniqueStrata(i)).size()
```

is supposed to do.  Maybe you could describe in words (or in R with some example code and data) what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I reformulate my question. Suppose we use "mtcars" dataset in R; data(mtcars). Suppose mtcars$cyl is my strata which we suppose here to be a character vector. mtcars$cyl has 03 distinct values. What I want to do is to have an rcpp implementation of the aggregate function in R. For example, I want the number of obs for each distinct value of mtcars$cyl

Comment: And what makes you think that just calling the `size()` member function would accomplish that?

Comment: strata(uniqueStrata(i)).size() is supposed to subset the vector and gives its length like the length function in R

Comment: I've never thought that "just calling size()" will solve the problem. That's why I'm asking